# Does Decentralized Cryptocurrency Exchange work for Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I know ETH works because it has a smart contract feature, what about Bitcoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, bitcoin have a simple but working scripting language so why not ? The most famous one is Bisq